# travis build fails running msbuild due to MSB4019

Tags: msbuild, wix, travis-ci

I am trying to build automatically a golang project in a windows environment with travis and to package the `.exe` making use of `msbuild` and `wix`.

The very same configuration works with Github actions and therefore I believe that both the `.wixproj` and the `wxs` are correct and there is some issue with the configuration of `msbuild` in the travis installation, but I have no more clues.

Possibly the msbuild installed by travis does not include the required wix toolset, I tried to install them, however while creating the package the error persist

---

The error

```
C:\Users\travis\gopath\src\github.com\gallo-cedrone\nri-elasticsearch\pkg\windows\nri-amd64-installer\nri-installer.wixproj" (default target) (1) ->
C:\Users\travis\gopath\src\github.com\gallo-cedrone\nri-elasticsearch\pkg\windows\nri-amd64-installer\nri-installer.wixproj(34,5): 
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets" was not found. 
Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

---

.travis

```
...
  - os: windows
    env:
    - MSBUILD_PATH="c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"
    before_script:
    - powershell Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core
    - cinst -y wixtoolset
    script:
    - export PATH=$MSBUILD_PATH:$PATH
    - go test ./src/
    - go build -v -o ./target/bin/windows_amd64/nri-elasticsearch.exe  ./src/
    - msbuild.exe -version
    - cd ./pkg/windows/nri-amd64-installer/ ; pwd ; env ; msbuild.exe ./nri-installer.wixproj
...
```

---

[travis job logs](https://travis-ci.org/gallo-cedrone/nri-elasticsearch/jobs/631957937)

Comment: Does imported target `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets"` exist on travis build agent? How does the `Import` on `wixproj` look like?

Comment: Also I didn't see a `WIX` env variable in your log, maybe something wrong with env variables? Have you followed this message 
_Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
 see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`)._?

Comment: Thanks @PavelAnikhouski you pointed me to the right direction, I was installing the tools correctly and reloading the shell, but the installation folder was not the expected one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to [enter link description here](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/wixtoolset/issues/5804/532663590)

Basically I was installing the wixtools, however the installation folder was not the expected one by vs2017.

It can be fixed simply by changing:
`<Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />`

with:

```
<Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' != '' " />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets') " />
```

and removing the `WixTargetsPath` clouses contitions.